# Facebook API not posting to facebook fan page PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First time dabbling in the facebook graph so please excuse my question if the fix is somewhat easy...

I have made my app, got all my appID and secret, and I am trying to post to a page as the page. I have granted the app permission, and done some debugging, however after the $facebook->api call, it just does nothing...

My code is as follows :

```
<?php
require 'core/components/facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '****',
    'secret' => '****',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
            $page_id = '****';
            $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
            if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
                $args = array(
                        'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
                        'message'       => "Testing"
                );
            //An echo of $page_info['access_token'] gives me an access token...
                $post_id = $facebook->api("/100160870061728/feed", "post", $args);
                //Does not echo below - help!
            echo "Success post id = " . $post_id;
            }
        else {
                $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
                if( !array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) || !array_key_exists('manage_pages', $permissions['data'][0])) {
                        header("Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream, manage_pages")));
                }
            }
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
    }
}

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} 
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'manage_pages, publish_stream'));
}

?>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass the `access_token` in your `$args`. You've already authenticated with `manage_pages` and `publish_stream`. When you authenticate via the PHP SDK this will be handled by your `$fb->api` call.

Comment: whats in your error log?

Comment: @cpilko, do you mean facebook will assume that the admin wants to post as page and use the page access token from their end? p.s. the code above is taken from my tutorial

Comment: @ifaour: Yes, that is what I've seen. If I authenticate as a user, I can publish to any of the pages I admin by POSTing to `/PAGE_ID/feed`.